# Игнорирование интерпретатором ввода от пользователя

Tags: python, python-3.x, функциональное-программирование

Здравствуйте. Никак не могу разобраться с проблемой.

Есть основной файл программы:

```
from functionsWithoutDeletions import coord_chr_uni_mod, inv_frag_calc, noninv_short_long_arm, arms_len_after_invers
variant = int(input('Выберете сценарий (0 или 1): '))
if variant == 0:
    invert_frag = inv_frag_calc()
    noninv_frag = noninv_short_long_arm(invert_frag)
    long_short_arm_len_cent_ind = arms_len_after_invers()
    print('Расчет завершен')
else:
    ...
```

В функции coord_chr_uni_mod тоже есть ввод от пользователя и в дальнейшем она запрашивается как параметр по умолчанию к функции inv_frag_calc.

Код функции:

```
def coord_chr_uni_mod():
    param_short_arm = int(input('Ввод данных: '))
    if param_short_arm != 0 and param_short_arm != 1:
        raise ValueError
    param_long_arm = int(input('Ввод данных: '))
    if param_long_arm != 0 and param_long_arm != 1:
        raise ValueError
    cent_coord = float(input('Ввод данных: '))
    if 0 >= cent_coord > 0.5:
        raise ValueError
    gene_short_arm = input_genes_short_arm()
    gene_long_arm = input_genes_long_arm() 
    norm_coord = None
    for i in range(len(gene_short_arm)):
        if param_short_arm == 0:
            norm_coord = gfunc.short_arm_cent_start(cent_coord, **gene_short_arm)
            print('Вывод')
        elif param_short_arm == 1:
            norm_coord = gfunc.short_arm_tel_start(cent_coord, **gene_short_arm)
            print('Вывод')

    norm_coord2 = None
    for i in range(len(gene_long_arm)):
        if param_long_arm == 0:
            norm_coord2 = gfunc.long_arm_cent_start(cent_coord, **gene_long_arm)
            print('Вывод')
        elif param_long_arm == 1:
            norm_coord2 = gfunc.long_arm_tel_start(cent_coord, **gene_long_arm)
            print('Вывод')
    return norm_coord, norm_coord2, cent_coord
```

Суть проблемы: при запуске программы игнорируется ввод в переменную variant, а вместо этого сразу запрашивается ввод из функции coord_chr_uni_mod. Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Выяснил в чем дело. Именно в том, что coord_chr_uni_mod запрашивалась как аргумент по умолчанию. Поэтому значения начинали заноситься в нее еще при импорте.